# Conditional statements within WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

Trying to write a conditional within my WP loop to show a different link based on the post ID.

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'post__in' => array( 116, 102 ) ) ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- LOOP STUFF HERE -->

<?php if ( is_tag( 'new-graduates' ) )  {  ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our new graduates</a></p>
<?php } elseif ( is_tag('experienced-hires') ) { ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our Experienced hires</a></p>
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The conditional is just being ignored with no output.

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
<?php query_posts( array ( 'post__in' => array( 116, 102 ) ) ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- LOOP STUFF HERE -->

<?php if ( has_tag( 'new-graduates' ) )  {  ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our new graduates</a></p>
<?php } elseif ( has_tag('experienced-hires') ) { ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our Experienced hires</a></p>
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Also, you forgot to ask the question, it seems.

Comment: Actually the wordpress loop is a real thing.  It is called in the documentation "The Loop".  It is how wordpress handles outputting multiple posts and such. But yes using PHP loops...

Comment: The question is that there is no output, and I'm looking for help not useless responses regarding my wording.

Comment: alright. Well the ifs syntax looks right, so it must be that your `is_tag()` returns false.

Comment: The post__in parameter will only return those two articles... is_tag returns if this is a tag archive page not if the post actually belongs to that tag.  So if you are receiving results... the is_tag is probably not the function you are looking for.  has_tag('TAGNAME') will probably work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with your code, this is happening because both `if` and `elseif` has failed, that's why you got no output.

Just add an `else` block like this ( just adding this to show your code is fine ) you will get the output.

```
<?php if ( has_tag( 'new-graduates' ) )  {  ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our new graduates</a></p>
<?php } elseif ( has_tag('experienced-hires') ) { ?>
<p class="jump-link"><a href="#">View our Experienced hires</a></p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p class="jump-link">No graduates nor Experienced</p>
<?php }?>
```